# In CakePhp, how can I retrieve the value of only one column from my database?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP but I have been using PHP for a while. I am trying to create a helper that would provide the level of access of a user (ACL).

Here is my ACLHelper.php so far

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ACLHelper extends Helper{
    public function getACL($id, $acl_field, $level){
        $members = TableRegistry::get('groups_member');
        $group = $members->find()->where(['user_id' => $id]);
        $acls = TableRegistry::get('acls');
        $acl = $acls->find('all', [ 'fields' => $acl_field ])->where(['group_id' => $group->first()->group_id]);
        return $acl->first();
    }
}
```

I call this function in my view this way

```
<?= $this->ACL->getACL($user->id, 'is_items', '4') ?>
```

And this is the output

```
{ "is_items": "4" }
```

What I need is the function to return true or false if the value of the field equals or is higher then the value of `$level` provided to the function. Now if I do this :

```
<?= $this->ACL->getACL($user->id, 'is_items', '4')->is_item ?>
```

it will return just the value. My problem is that I do not want to specify the field twice.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getACL($id, $acl_field, $level){
    $members = TableRegistry::get('groups_member');
    $group = $members->find()->where(['user_id' => $id]);
    $acls = TableRegistry::get('acls');
    // Get the first ACL record right here
    $acl = $acls->find('all', [ 'fields' => $acl_field ])->where(['group_id' => $group->first()->group_id])->first();
    // Compare the requested field against the provided level
    return $acl->$acl_field >= $level;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Worked for me